# MPAndroidChart giving weird x axis values

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm developing fitness application where I would like to display chart of user running activities over months, so something like this:
[Graph how I want it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEqrj.png)

I'm using MPAndroidChart for it, but I'm getting some weird values on the x axis (the y axis is alright).

I have a map (monthMileage in the code sample), where the key is the month and the year in string, so for example Jul 2020 as "072020" and the value is the total distance of km which user ran that month.

```
profileViewModel.monthOverview.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { monthMileage ->
            val entries = ArrayList<BarEntry>()
            for ((k, v) in monthMileage) {
                entries.add(BarEntry(k, v.toFloat()))
            }
            val dataSet = BarDataSet(entries, "Monthly mileage")
            val barData = BarData(dataSet)
            activity_graph.xAxis.labelCount = entries.size
            activity_graph.xAxis.valueFormatter = ActivityGraphFormatter()
            activity_graph.axisRight.axisMinimum = 0.toFloat()
            activity_graph.axisLeft.axisMinimum = 0.toFloat()
            activity_graph.data = barData
            activity_graph.invalidate()
        })
```

This is how I'm trying to set data to the Bar Chart. The x value is the month-year string to Float and y is the total distance. I use custom value formatter, which looks weird, but should be working with the right values (and the values are still wrong even when I don't use the formatter so there's error probably somewhere else). In the whole process the values in the entries, data set and data are still the values I'm expecting, but when it's set to the graph it's just wrong.

For example for 72020 and 62020 I'm getting 65000 and 70000.

There's probably some correlation I don't see so I welcome all advicess or if anybody knows about some nicer chart library for android mobile app, I've been searching, but all the time everybody is just praising MPAndroidChart.

Comment: Hi @Fukalhan ! You've mentioned you're using a custom x axis value formatter. Can you, please, share the snippet of it?